# How can I vectorize the following loops in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am using an R2019a matlab.
I have a matrix that I want to fill with values at certain positions, based on a calculation done on 2 additional vectors.
Currently I'm doing it with 2 loop, but this doesn't take advantage of matlab's vectorization abilities.

How can the following script be performed in a vectorized manner:

```
C = zeros(size(vecB), size(vecA));

% Calculate face-vertix connectivity of face area values:
posMat = sparse(A, repmat((1:size(A,1))',1,3), ...
                1, size(B,1), size(A,1));

for i = 1:size(B,1)
    for j = 1:size(A,1)
        if posMat(i,j) == 1
            C(i,j) = vecA(j)/vecB(i)/3;
        end
    end
end
```

Sizes of variables in the script:

```
size(A)  =         5120           3
size(B)  =         2562           3
size(B)  =         2562        5120
size(posMat)  =    2562        5120
size(vecA) =       5120           1
size(vecB) =       2562           1
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? Why are you using `sparse`? What is `mesh`? Without a [mcve] it is impossible for us to validate any suggested improvements. You should be able to just do `C = vecA ./ (vecB.') ./ 3; C( posMat ~= 1 ) = 0;` if you have R2016b or newer, or equivalent with `bsxfun` before then.

Comment: And, just to spread the word: [Matlab is no longer slow at for loops](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/) - from 2012!

Comment: @HansHirse however loops that enumerate all elements of a sparse matrix *are* slow, at least compared to elementwise sparse array methods

Comment: @obchardon Octave ≠ Matlab

Comment: @HansHirse: And that blog post was about the old JIT. [The new JIT in R2015b](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/) really changed how I program in MATLAB.

Comment: I appreciate all the help. Regarding matlab's improved ability with loops. For this problem, using loops took about a 20 seconds of processing time compared to less than a second for the solution provided by "Wolfie" and "Will".

Comment: @Mark.F: Yes, Will’s answer uses the fact that you have a sparse matrix, it doesn’t loop over all `i,j`. It is *a better algorithm*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the condition inside your loop is only satisfied by nonzero elements of `posMat`, the important thing for efficiency is to take advantage of the fact that this matrix is `sparse` in a vectorized implementation.

If you use multiplication by a `sparse` condition as the means of setting the elements that fail the condition to `0` (rather than initializing the matrix using `zeros`) then only the elements that pass the condition will actually be evaluated.

From R2016b onwards, `vecA.'./vecB/3` is [implicitly expanded](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) to return the full `2562×5120 double array` of `vecA(j)/vecB(i)/3` for *all* values of `i` and `j`. But `(posMat == 1) .* vecA.'./vecB/3` returns a `2562×5120 sparse double array` where the division has only been evaluated for the elements where `posMat == 1`.

If a `sparse` value of `C` if acceptable, then

```
C = (posMat == 1) .* vecA.'./vecB/3;
```

will suffice. If the full-storage form is required this output can simply be passed to the `full` function.